# Ionic proxy config for different environments

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic and I try to setup a proxy configuration for different environments. I have several environment-specific config files in place which get loaded using webpack and an environment variable which is set before ionic is served (see: https://github.com/gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables).

Everything works as expected but I don’t know how to solve following issue:
My proxy configuration (ionic.config.json) looks like this:

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://dv.mydomain.com/api",
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
  ]
```

and one of my http calls looks like this:

```
return this.http.get<User[]>(ENV.apiUrl + '/api/users')
```

I have to remove ENV.apiUrl because otherwise the pattern specified in the proxy config doesn’t get matched, but if I do so, I cannot distinguish between different environments anymore. I have tried to add the domain to the path of the proxy configuration, which did not work.

Is there a way to solve this issue?
I asked the same question in the ionic forum but no one answered so far.

Comment: Can you add more info regarding the ENV.apiUrl?

Comment: Sure thing. Please click on the link in the first paragraph, the readme explains where it comes from, what it does and why it's needed. My app communicates with three test environments and one productive environment.

Answer (score 0):

The way I "solved" it so far is not to use Ionic proxies anymore. I've installed [this plugin for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), which basically disables chrome's CORS protection by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Can't the apiUrl just be a URL path component? Ex:

```
// environment.pro.ts
export const environment: any = {
    apiUrl: '/pro'
};

// environment.dev.ts
export const environment: any = {
    apiUrl: '/dev'
};
```

Then, something like:

```
// ionic.config.json
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/pro/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://example.com/api",
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
  },
  {
    "path": "/dev/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://dev.example.com/api",
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Not possible for me, that would have worked of course, but was not the question. Please read my own answer below. That's how it can be solved.

Comment: Cannot work, as the `ionic.config.json` isn't used whenever we're the `ionic cli` isn't used, typically on devices.

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue will only be specific to the local development as Ionic uses browser for local developement.
In mobile all the javascript will be copied as file://
Thus origin will not be exist.

So to handle this you can install the chrome extention 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

This should solve the problem.